# Regex to look for url start value and end value

Tags: regex

I'm using using regex to look for URL that starts with `http` or `https` and  with a specific value.

```
^http|https\:\/\/www
```

This regex looks at the http/https in a URL and this works.

```
/[\/]\bvalue?\b[\/]/g
```

This regex looks for "value" in a url and this currently matches with

```
http://www.test.co.uk/value/
http://www.test.co.uk/folder/value/
```

Is there a possibility to put those two regex together? Basically I need to display URLs that doesn't contain `http/https` or `/value/` in the URL path

Comment: `^http|https\:\/\/www` only checks if a string starts with `http` or contains `https://www`.

Comment: my 2cents: logically speaking looking for http will also yield https, so you only need to find http

Comment: I'd use two regexps, they are short and clear. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eo1f3mra/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking to do this: `/(?=^(https|http))|(\bvalue\b)/g`

First half: `(?=^(https|http))` which will look first for https and then for http. My personal opinion however is to reduce the code to look only for http, since by matching for http you can also match for https. You may think this behavior is not going to work, but logically it does. You can try that if you like and see what happens.

Second half: `(\bvalue\b)`. You can be more specific such as it being between forward and back slashes, or not. I used the `\b` delimiter to avoid it being part of another string and it worked quite well.

The *important part here* is to unite them, so use the `|` operator and it yields the above result.

Test strings:

```
http://www.helloworldvalue/value/values/
https://www.helloworldvalue/values/svalue/value/value/vaaluevalue/
```

Try it and let me know if you have any questions in the comments below.